# Laravel create array from model

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to format the output of an `Eloquent` query to use in `Highmaps`

My code:

```
$regsByCtry = $regsByCtryArr->pluck('ctry', 'val')->map(function($country, $value) {
    return [
        "hc-key" => $country,
        "value"  => $value
    ];
})->toJson();
```

Outputs:

```
"{
  "1": {"hc-key":"br","value":1},
  "5": {"hc-key":"au","value":5}
 }"
```

I am trying to output the JSON without the keys, as an collection of objects:

```
"{
  {"hc-key":"br","value":1},
  {"hc-key":"au","value":5}
 }"
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use values chained method

```
$regsByCtry = $regsByCtryArr->pluck('ctry', 'val')->values()->map(function($country, $value) {
    return [
        "hc-key" => $country,
        "value"  => $value
    ];
})->values()->toJson();
```

Comment: is it solution ?